# JWT token parsing and Claims authentication in .Net 4.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, jwt

My company wants to start using Open ID connect for it's authorization and identity. The website is .Net 4.0 so OWIN is out. I've searched and searched but I cant find a 4.0 compatible library. Does anyone know of a library for parsing JWT tokens (or even better, converts them into claims) that is build for .Net 4.0?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/

Comment: Thanks Robert. I'm looking at that. I'll post my results.

Comment: Nope. It doesnt support 4.0